# How to Generate and Verify Checksum of a file without downloading the file in Node JS

Tags: node.js, checksum

Is there a way to generate a checksum of an mp3 file without downloading it?

I am using the crypto library, but it seems that I have to download the file.

Comment: No, to calculate the checksum for a bunch of data, you have t have this data available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a "checksum" is a value derived from a collection of data, you'd need a copy of those data to be able to generate the checksum.